# iPhone App Submission - Bluetooth BLE Enable

Tags: ios7, core-bluetooth

Can anyone tell me how apple handle submissions for bluetooth BLE enabled app. Actually, i have created a bluetooth iphone app which connects to third party device. And, I am not sure how apple is testing apps which connects to third party devices.

Comment: Do we need to have MFi Program enrollment for uploading iOS app to App store that connects to third part devices using bluetooth or BLE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Object Lab](http://objectlab.github.io/) has recently launched their first iOS app using iBeacon. It took them 3 attempts to get it approved. I would recommend you to create a video which demonstrates how your app works and send it to them.

Generally they ask for hardware as well but mostly it's not feasible for us to provide them with one. Object Lab had to send them instructions to setup hardware at their end and to test the app. THEY WILL NOT APPROVE UNLESS THEY KNOW ITS WORKING. So I would recommend to send a video and step by step instruction of how to setup hardware at their end to test it out.

Comment: How did you send them the video?

Comment: make a video upload on youtube and send them the url

Comment: I've submitted an app with iBeacon functionality on iOS (early '14) and didn't have to provide any hardware or videos or explanation. The beacon functionality wasn't prominent in the app though, it seems theirs was the whole point of the app so that might be why it needed to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that a video demonstrating the use of the app while connected to your third party device is enough.  Sending the device to them is not necessary (at least for all cases).  I know there is another thread on stackoverflow.com concerning this very thing, but it's been months since I had found it and I can't find it now. Anyways, it has worked for me as well as acquaintances of mine who have an app on the store.